# List spacing being ignored in parcolumns environment

Tags: lists, margins, itemize, parcolumns

I am trying to make a 2 column resume using `parcolumns` but I am having a problem where any changes I make to the `itemize` or `description` environments are ignored if they are inside the `parcolumns` environment. I have also tried setting the lengths using `\setlength` but that is not working either. For example in the picture I wanted to increase the spacing between items and the top and bottom list margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Style lists
\def\labelitemi{--}
\setitemize{noitemsep, topsep=0.5em, leftmargin=0.2in, itemsep=0.5em}
\setdescription{nolistsep, itemsep=3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent, rulebetween, colwidths={1=1.5in, 2=6in}]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\sc Education}

\colchunk[2]{
\textbf{Blah blah}\hfill{Some place} \newline
\textit{lalalalallala} \hfill{\textit{2010 -- 2014}}
\begin{itemize}
\item test
\item test
\item test
\end{itemize}
}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}


\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

You can regain your list style by encapsulating it in a `minipage`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,margin=.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{parcolumns}
\usepackage{enumitem}

% Style lists
\setlist[itemize]{noitemsep, topsep=0.5cm, leftmargin=0.2in,
itemsep=0.5em}
\setlist[itemize,1]{label=--}
\setlist[description]{nolistsep, itemsep=3em}

\begin{document}

\begin{parcolumns}[nofirstindent, rulebetween, colwidths={1=1.5in, 2=6in}]{2}
\colchunk[1]{\sc Education}

\colchunk[2]{
\textbf{Blah blah}\hfill Some place

\textit{lalalalallala} \hfill \textit{2010 -- 2014}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\mbox{}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item test
  \item test
  \item test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test test test test test test
    test test test test test test test test
  \item test
  \end{itemize}
\end{minipage}
}
\colplacechunks
\end{parcolumns}

\end{document}
```

I have used the newer syntax for setting the list styles in `enumitem`.